# helm: how to check if a service with prefix already exists in namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to implement some k8s services only if there is a service with suffix "mysuffix" in the namespace. I tried the following but doesn't work

```
{{- $previousReleaseInstalled := false -}}
{{- range $index, $service := (lookup "v1" "Service" .Release.Namespace "").items }}
{{- if hasSuffix "mysuffix" "$service.name" }}
{{- $previousReleaseInstalled := true -}}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}


{{- if $previousReleaseInstalled -}}
implement some services
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `lookup` function is almost correct. The issue with the assignment of the `$previousReleaseInstalled` variable. You need to use `=` instead of `:=` inside the `range`. Check this answer for the details [Why doesn't this change the value of the variable in the range loop in Helm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64272789/why-doesnt-this-change-the-value-of-the-variable-in-the-range-loop-in-helm)

Another issue is the wrong key name. You should use `$service.metadata.name` instead of `$service.name`, and remove the quotes around the `$service.metadata.name`

```
{{- $previousReleaseInstalled := false -}}
{{- range $index, $service := (lookup "v1" "Service" .Release.Namespace 
"").items }}
{{- if hasSuffix "mysuffix" $service.metadata.name }}
{{- $previousReleaseInstalled = true -}}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}


{{- if $previousReleaseInstalled -}}
implement some services
{{- end }}
```

Another important thing to note, the `lookup` function always returns empty response when used with the `helm template` command. https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lookup